# How to get the output for date in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, date

I did write this script in javascript, to get the date output. Now that I have changed the background script to PHP I need the code to get the date in below format.

I also tried to get the date but was getting the previous day and not the current one.

```
Date.prototype.toFormattedString = function (f)

{
    var nm = this.getMonthName();
    var nd = this.getDayName();
    f = f.replace(/yyyy/g, this.getFullYear());
    f = f.replace(/yy/g, String(this.getFullYear()).substr(2,2));
    f = f.replace(/MMM/g, nm.substr(0,3).toUpperCase());
    f = f.replace(/Mmm/g, nm.substr(0,3));
    f = f.replace(/MM\*/g, nm.toUpperCase());
    f = f.replace(/Mm\*/g, nm);
    f = f.replace(/mm/g, String(this.getUTCMonth()+1).padLeft('0',2));
    f = f.replace(/DDD/g, nd.substr(0,3).toUpperCase());
    f = f.replace(/Ddd/g, nd.substr(0,3));
    f = f.replace(/DD\*/g, nd.toUpperCase());
    f = f.replace(/Dd\*/g, nd);
    f = f.replace(/dd/g, String(this.getUTCDate()).padLeft('0',2));
    f = f.replace(/d\*/g, this.getUTCDate());
    return f;
};

Date.prototype.getMonthName = function ()
{
    return this.toLocaleString().replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'');
};


Date.prototype.getDayName = function ()
{
    switch(this.getDay())
    {
        case 0: return 'Sunday';
        case 1: return 'Monday';
        case 2: return 'Tuesday';
        case 3: return 'Wednesday';
        case 4: return 'Thursday';
        case 5: return 'Friday';
        case 6: return 'Saturday';
    }
};

String.prototype.padLeft = function (value, size) 
{
    var x = this;
    while (x.length < size) {x = value + x;}
    return x;
};


var now = (new Date()).toFormattedString('yyyymmdd')
```

I need output like `20150221`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use date like this :

```
<?php

$current_day = date('Ymd');
echo $current_day;

?>
```

You can find more options in

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.<br/> Will this take the system time?<br/> My website will be used in different parts of the world if the current date is not matched then the script will fail...

Comment: Is this correct ? <br/>
$currentdatetime "(date('Ymd')";
echo $currentdatetime

Comment: Sir, I need to link the  date('Ymd'); to $currentdatetime, How to do it??

Comment: What do you mean with link? Something like this $currentdatetime =  date('Ymd');

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code to get the date in PHP

```
<?php
   echo date('Ymd');
?>
```

EDIT: The format is 20150221

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = new DateTime()->format('Ymd');
```

Read the PHP documentation on the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using Carbon, it's really easy and it makes easier the development, you can check it out in here https://github.com/briannesbitt/carbon

Here's an example of the usage of carbon

```
<?php
printf("Right now is %s", Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
printf("Right now in Vancouver is %s", Carbon::now('America/Vancouver'));  //implicit __toString()
$tomorrow = Carbon::now()->addDay();
$lastWeek = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
```

The documentation explains it all with great detail, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

**Local System Date:**

If your script needs date of the local system i.e. the system of the    person who will use your application via browser, then you should go    for JavaScript date and not PHP. In this case, the system date may    differ as users will access it from different region. Also, they can    adjust their system date.

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getTime(); //output e.g. 1424497935248
```

**Server System Date:**

If your script needs the server date, irrespective of the date of    local system, then you should go for PHP date.

```
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"); //sample output 2015-02-21 06:00:15am
echo time(); //sample output 1424498415
```